# How to add a space after each number of output to separate them

Tags: c

In this loop I print each of the values in an array "values."  They appear as 93832734557896 instead of 9383 2734 557 896, etc:

```
for( n = 0 ; n < num_values; n++ ) {
    printf("%llu", values[n]); }
```

I want to print a space after each number, not a newline.  How can I do that with printf?

Thanks

Comment: Add a space in the format string printf("%llu ", values[n]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space in your `printf` statement:

```c
printf("%llu ", values[n]);
//          ^ notice the space here
```

Comment: and Vlad from moscow - that works.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

To print a space between the numbers only, without a leading or trailing space for the entire data printed, you can use a variable separator string:

```
const char *separator = "";
for( n = 0 ; n < num_values; n++ ) {
    printf("%s%llu", separator, values[n]);
    separator = " ";
}
```

Note that the separator starts as a zero-length string, is printed *before* the value, and is then set to a string that contains a single space.

This technique is also well-suited for printing comma-separated data.

Comment: UV... This is the better answer, so far (imo).

Comment: @Fe2O3 I wish I remember who taught me this technique - it's really useful for emitting data with separators.  Just change `separator = " ";` to `separator = ",";` and you're emitting CSV data.

Comment: I probably am too fond of ternary expressions, but I'd write
`for (n = 0; n < num_values; n++) {
    printf("%s%llu", (i==0 ? "" : " "), values[n];
}`

Answer (score 1):

One can compress the (better, so far) answer given by @AndrewHenle:

```
for( n = 0 ; n < num_values; n++ )
    printf( "%s%llu", &" "[!n], values[n] );
```

When `n == 0` (`!n` == true == 1), this addresses the `'\0'` at the end of the two byte string.

When `n > 0` (`!n` == false == 0), the `" "` is printed as a string.

No need for an extraneous variable.

**EDIT:**
No need for taxing the `printf()` processing with 2x'%' and 3 parameters:

```
    for (int n = 0; n < num_values; n++)
        printf( &" %llu"[!n], values[n] ); // skip leading SP when n == 0
```

Same idea using `!n` yielding the results `1, 0, 0, 0, ...` offseting from the start of the string
`" %llu"`. The "zero-th" value is printed without the leading space. Subsequent iterations include the leading space.

Comment: Nice.  My own personal preference is to rely on my compiler's optimizer to remove the admittedly-extraneous code.  But if you don't have such a compiler for your target platform...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks... :-) I don't have such a compiler... And, I just like less code... The _comment_ (missing from this code), making the operation plain, would be understood by any experienced programmer... Cheers! :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Just posted a "code golf" _improvement_ (???) `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Turn your thought process around. Add a space *before* each output except the first. That can be done trivially with the *ternary* operator, e.g.

```c
for (int n = 0; n < num_values; n++) {
  printf (n ? " %llu" : "%llu", values[n]);
}
```

(**note:** with this method you benefit by not having stray whitespace dangling off the end of your line of output)

Full example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  
  long long unsigned values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  int num_values = sizeof values / sizeof *values; 
  
  for (int n = 0; n < num_values; n++) {
    printf (n ? " %llu" : "%llu", values[n]);
  }
  putchar ('\n');

}
```

**output**

```
$ ./bin/ternary-space-control
1 2 3 4
```